# NuSOAP usando Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Estou criando um Webservice no Laravel com a biblioteca [Noiselabs](https://packagist.org/packages/noiselabs/nusoap-bundle).

```
Route::any('x/ws/hello', function(){
    $server = new \soap_server;

    $server->configureWSDL('server.hello', 'urn:server.hello');
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server.hello';

    $server->register('hello',
            array('name' => 'xsd:string'),
            array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
            'urn:server.hello',
            'urn:server.hello#hello',
            'rpc',
            'encoded',
            'Retorna o nome'
    );

    function hello($name)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $name;
    }

    // requisição para uso do serviço
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
    $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
});
```

[image]

Até ai tudo bem.

Só que quando tento mostrar o XML gerado com ?wsdl no final da URL dá um problema.
Gera um HTML do XML gerado.

[image]

Achei que poderia ser o debug que eu estou usando com Laravel, mas coloquei false no aquivo app.php e também continuou do mesmo jeito.

[image]

Quando faço com PHP puro funcionou.

O meu cliente tá desse jeito.

```
Route::get('x/client/hello', function(){
    // criação de uma instância do cliente
    $client = new \nusoap_client('http://localhost/registro_aplicativos/public/x/ws/hello?wsdl', true);
    // verifica se ocorreu erro na criação do objeto

    $result = $client->call('hello', array('Renato Araujo'));
    // exibe o resultado
    var_dump($result);

    echo '<h2>Requisição</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request) . '</pre>';
    echo '<h2>Resposta</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response) . '</pre>';
    // Exibe mensagens para debug
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
    echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str) . '</pre>';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de umas pesquisas consegui resolver.

Usei o Response::make(); do Laravel.

```
Route::any('x/ws/hello', function(){
    $server = new \soap_server;

    $server->configureWSDL('server.hello', 'urn:server.hello');
    $server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'urn:server.hello';

    $server->register('hello',
        array('name' => 'xsd:string'),
        array('return' => 'xsd:string'),
        'urn:server.hello',
        'urn:server.hello#hello',
        'rpc',
        'encoded',
        'Retorna o nome'
    );

    function hello($name)
    {
        return 'Hello ' . $name;
    }

    // requisição para uso do serviço
    $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

    return Response::make($server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'text/xml', 'charset' => 'ISO-8859-1'));
```

});

Answer (score 0):

O que está acontecendo é que o navegador está automaticamente "interpretando" o XML e apresentando o resultado transformado em HTML.

A chave para mudar esse comportamento é mudar o cabeçalho (header) HTTP que informa o "Content-Type" do conteúdo enviado para o navegador.

Verifique qual é o **Content-Type** que o servidor HTTP está enviando para o navegador. (Use o Firebug ou outra ferramenta de desenvolvimento.) Creio que seja "**text/xml**".

Para mudar o Content-Type, há varias alternativas. Neste caso, precisamos de uma ajudinha com *output buffering* ("controle de saída"):

```
// requisição para uso do serviço
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';

// iniciamos o output buffering...
ob_start();

// ...para podermos chamar a função do nuSOAP
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

// aqui sobrescrevemos o Content-Type (use o charset apropriado)
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n");

// e finalmente liberamos o conteúdo do buffer
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: Fiz o que você falou, mas mesmo assim não deu.